# When do Fourier series converge uniformly almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be $2\pi$-periodic, $f\in L^1[0,2\pi]$, with fourier series $\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n \cos n\theta + b_n \sin n\theta)$. What condition must we impose upon $f$, s.t. $\exists E\subset[0,2\pi]$ s.t. $[0,2\pi]\setminus E$ has measure-zero, and $\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n \cos n\theta + b_n \sin n\theta)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} f(\theta)$ uniformly on $E$?

Comment: If $f$ is of bounded variation and continuous on $[0,2\pi]$ with $f(0)=f(2\pi)$, then the Fourier series converges uniformly to $f$. This condition is sufficient but not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $s_n$ converges uniformly on a set of full measure then $s_n$ converges uniformly, period. (If $|s_n-s_m|<\epsilon$ on $E$ then $|s_n-s_m|\le\epsilon$ everywhere.)

So at a minimum you need $f=g$ almost everywhere, with $g$ continuous. Of course that's far from sufficient. But the question is really about uniformly convergent Fourier series, without the "almost everywhere"; this is a well-studied topic. (Of course $\sum(|a_n|+|b_n|)<\infty$ is sufficient...
)